# Как сделать вывод в карточке товара woocommerce множества вариаций этого товара с разными ценами и с возможностью выбора их количества?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress + woocommerce. Мелкооптовый магазин. Есть товары с единым названием и внешним видом, которые отличаются только одной характеристикой. Но цены отличаются. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на карточке товара выводились все эти товары в виде строк с чекбоксом и полем выбора количества для каждого. И в корзину нужно передавать как один товар с разными вариантами и количеством для каждого. На странице оформления все цены должны суммироваться в цену одного товара.
"Групповой товар" не подходит, так как товаров тысячи, а вариаций десятки. Получится огромное количество товаров, которые усложнят жизнь движку и потребуют много ресурсов сервера. И при оформлении заказа получится огромная портянка, так как клиенты заказывают по несколько видов товаров сразу (а иногда и десятки).
Решение нужно любое: хоть кодом, хоть плагином.
Спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понятно что ты хочешь. Нарисуй скрин, что ли.